# pg_restore: error: could not execute query: ERROR: option "locale" not recognized

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump, pg-restore

I'm getting the following error when I'm trying to restore my dump file to another (local) PostgreSQL server (running on Debian GNU/Linux 10.10):

```
pg_restore: error: could not execute query: ERROR:  option "locale" not recognized
```

because it indeed has the following line:

```
CREATE DATABASE "REMOTE_DB" WITH TEMPLATE = template0 ENCODING = 'UTF8' LOCALE = 'en_GB.UTF-8';
```

And yes, I **know** that *PostgreSQL 12* [CREATE DATABASE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-createdatabase.html) command doesn't have a `LOCALE` option.

What I don't understand:

- the version of PostgreSQL itself I'm using on my local server, is reported as 12.7
- the version of `pg_dump` I'm using on my local server is reported as 12.7
- the version of `pg_restore` I'm using on my local server is reported as 12.7
- the remote PostgreSQL database whose dump I've created using `pg_dump` is version 12.7, *not 13*.

Let me verify these one by one:

My local server:

```
$ sudo -u postgres psql -c 'select version();'
                                                     version
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 12.7 (Debian 12.7-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
```

My local `pg_dump` version:

```
$ pg_dump --version
pg_dump (PostgreSQL) 12.7 (Debian 12.7-1.pgdg100+1)
```

My local `pg_restore` version:

```
$ pg_restore --version
pg_restore (PostgreSQL) 12.7 (Debian 12.7-1.pgdg100+1)
```

Let's check the PostgreSQL version of the *REMOTE* database:

```
$ psql --host=REMOTE_HOST_IP_ADDRESS --dbname=REMOTE_DB --username=DB_USER -c 'select version();'
Password for user DB_USER:
                                                             version
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 12.7 (Debian 12.7-1.pgdg90+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 6.3.0 20170516, 64-bit
(1 row)
```

This is how I created the dump file:

```
$ pg_dump --verbose \
  --create \
  --clean \
  --if-exists \
  --format=custom \
  --compress=5 \
  --host=REMOTE_HOST_IP_ADDRESS --dbname=REMOTE_DB --username=DB_USER \
  --schema=public --table=TABLE_NAME\
  > db.dump
```

And this is how I tried to restore it on the local server that's running PostgreSQL 12:

```
$ sudo -u postgres \
pg_restore --verbose \
  --create \
  --clean \
  --jobs=8 \
  --format=custom \
  --dbname=postgres \
  db.dump
```

**PostgreSQL 13** is installed but it's not running on this local server:

```
$ systemctl status postgresql@13-main.service
● postgresql@13-main.service - PostgreSQL Cluster 13-main
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql@.service; enabled-runtime; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: protocol) since Thu 2021-06-24 07:59:24 UTC; 1 day 5h ago
  Process: 562 ExecStart=/usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster --skip-systemctl-redirect 13-main start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

**PostgreSQL 12** is running:

```
$ systemctl status postgresql@12-main.service
● postgresql@12-main.service - PostgreSQL Cluster 12-main
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql@.service; enabled-runtime; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2021-06-24 07:59:26 UTC; 1 day 5h ago
  Process: 556 ExecStart=/usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster --skip-systemctl-redirect 12-main start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 595 (postgres)
    Tasks: 9 (limit: 36863)
   Memory: 235.7M
   CGroup: /system.slice/system-postgresql.slice/postgresql@12-main.service
           ├─595 /usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin/postgres -D /var/lib/postgresql/12/main -c config_file=/etc/postgresql/12/main/postgresql.conf
           ├─678 postgres: 12/main: checkpointer
           ├─679 postgres: 12/main: background writer
           ├─680 postgres: 12/main: walwriter
           ├─681 postgres: 12/main: autovacuum launcher
           ├─682 postgres: 12/main: stats collector
           ├─683 postgres: 12/main: TimescaleDB Background Worker Launcher
           ├─684 postgres: 12/main: logical replication launcher
           └─685 postgres: 12/main: TimescaleDB Background Worker Scheduler
```

Long story short, my question is:

- why do I get this unsupported `LOCALE` option in the dump file generated by `pg_dump`, while the REMOTE PostgreSQL version, as well as local `pg_dump` version is reported as **12.7** and ***not*** **13**?

What else should I check?

Comment: Some things are done with sudo and some are done without it.  Maybe you are finding different binaries depending on sudo usage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> the version of PostgreSQL itself I'm using on my local server, is
> reported as 12.7

But still it's pg_dump 13.x that created the dump with the `LOCALE` argument to `CREATE DATABASE`.

`/usr/bin/pg_dump` as installed by Debian/Ubuntu packages is a wrapper that tries
to determine which version of PostgreSQL it should talk to, and then
it executes the actual binary inside `/usr/lib/postgresql/$VERSION/bin/`. This is meant to support multiple installations and versions of PostgreSQL on the same host, even if only one is running in your case.

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/pg_dump
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 37 Aug 14  2020 /usr/bin/pg_dump -> ../share/postgresql-common/pg_wrapper
```

See [pg_wrapper](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/postgresql-client-common/pg_wrapper.1.en.html) for the manpage.

### Plausible explanation

When executing `pg_dump --version`, it somehow picks up the version of your active cluster (12) and launches the corresponding pg_dump.

When executing `pg_dump --host ...`, it doesn't know which version of PostgreSQL the remote host is running, and somehow chooses version 13 by default.

### Solution

As a workaround, you may invoke directly `/usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin/pg_dump` instead of `pg_dump`

Comment: If you're running on a Mac and have postgresql installed via Homebrew there's no wrapper, so instead the workaround is to install version 12 (or other) like `brew install postgresql@12`, then calling  `/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@12/12.7/bin/pg_dump